# pip でインストールエラー: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed

Tags: python, anaconda, python2

現在、Windows10でanaconda2環境があります。
そこで、他のモジュールをpipでインストールしようとすると、決まって次のインストールエラーが生じます。

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users********\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-d32tg1\unroll\

このエラーは一体どんなエラーなのでしょうか。
対応策がありましたら、教えて頂けないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users********\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-d32tg1\unroll\」がエラーメッセージの全文ですか？

Comment: 半分回答をしておきました。pipの側にもバグがあると思うのですが、他のモジュールのインストールはできているでしょうか？

Comment: 返事がないので回答を修正しました。また、この問題はWindows10、anaconda2という環境の問題ではなく、一般的な問題なのでタイトルとタグを修正しておきました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

このエラーは`unroll`というパッケージをインストールするのに失敗しているのが原因です。

英語版でも同じ質問 [“pip install unroll”: “python setup.py egg_info” failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403) があって、プラス投票が227あって、このエラーに困っている人が多くいるのではないかと思います。また、回答が18というのはかなり混乱した状態です。

このエラーの原因には、2つの要素が絡んでいるのが、英語版の方で混乱している理由です。

1番目は、`pip`にバグがあったことです。インストール中にエラーになれば、インストールせずに終了しないといけないのに、中途半端な処理が行われ結果として毎回エラーになるというバグです。このバグについては修正されているので、`pip`と`setuptools`をアップグレードすることで解消できます。`pip`と`setuptools`のアップグレードは以下のようにしてできます。

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

ただし、anacondaの場合は、

```
conda update pip setuptools
```

2番目は、`unroll`のパッケージににもバグがあります。

メンテナンスされているパッケージであれば、バグがあれば修正されるので`pip install unroll`とすればすむことなのですが、`unroll`というパッケージが2014年4月16日に公開されて以降全くサポートがされていません。それで、`pip install unroll`で発生するエラーを自分で解消する必要があります。

`pip install unroll`とすると、まず、`ez-setup`というパッケージがないというエラーが出るので、`ez-setup`をインストールします。

```
pip install ez-setup
```

`ez-setup`をインストール後`pip install unroll`とすると下にあるようなエラーが発生します。`http`で`PyPI`にアクセスしていますが、`PyPI`は2017年の後半から`https`が必須になっています。それで、ソースコードを修正する必要があるのですが、GitHubにあるソースは`https`を使うようになっているので、そちらを使うとインストールできます。

```
git clone https://github.com/Zulko/unroll
pip install ./unroll
```

又は `Download ZIP` ( https://github.com/Zulko/unroll/archive/master.zip )して、

```
pip install unroll-master.zip
```

`unroll`は、メンテナスされていないパッケージです。このようなパッケージはトラブルの元になりやすいので注意してください。

```
Collecting unroll
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fe/3c/124bdf4276e582c8e4e23ce27c4462a259f6608df8e550d30f003f2b4189/unroll-0.1.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.14.tar.gz
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-GluuOx/unroll/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
        ez_setup.use_setuptools()
      File "/home/niji/opt/app/test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ez_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
        return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
      File "/home/niji/opt/app/test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ez_setup.py", line 124, in _do_download
        to_dir, download_delay)
      File "/home/niji/opt/app/test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ez_setup.py", line 193, in download_setuptools
        src = urlopen(url)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 473, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-GluuOx/unroll/
```