# Pipインストールでエラー: “python setup.py egg_info” failed with error code 1

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

```
$ pip install -r .examples/requirements.txt
```

を実行したところ

```
Command “python setup.py egg_info” failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-VIFN4h/sacrebleu/
```

というエラーが出ました。
またこれまで、

```
$ pip install - -upgrade setuptools
```

を行いましたが効果がありませんでした。

このエラーを解決する方法を教えてください。

＜追記＞
紹介していただいた記事を読んで、pip setuptoolsをupgradeしていなかったことに気がつき、次のコマンドを実行しました。

```
$ pip install - -upgrade pip
```

すると、エラーの内容がつぎのように変わりました。

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-jEHSxk/sacrebleu/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-jEHSxk/sacrebleu/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-jEHSxk/sacrebleu/pip-egg-info
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-jEHSxk/sacrebleu/
Complete output (7 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-jEHSxk/sacrebleu/setup.py", line 65, in <module>
    version = get_version(),
  File "/tmp/pip-install-jEHSxk/sacrebleu/setup.py", line 56, in get_version
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'sacrebleu.py'), encoding='utf-8') as fin:
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: 調べるのにこの記事の後半が参考になりそうです。[【Python】「Command “python setup.py egg_info” failed with error code 1 in …」の対処法](https://keymaso.com/programemory/python/pip-error-1/) 後は発生パッケージが`sacrebleu`でしょうからこんなIssueの情報も。[v1.4.6 broke some imports #71](https://github.com/mjpost/sacrebleu/issues/71)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。解決に近づきました。

Comment: `encoding`が使えないというのは、2.x系のPythonにインストールしようとしているのでは？ こちらでは `Python::3::Only`と書かれています。[sacrebleu・PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/sacrebleu/)

Comment: インストールする際にpython3を指定するには、どのようにすれば良いですか？

Comment: 使う`pip`を`pip3`にしてみては？

Comment: 上手く行きました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントで解決したようなので記録として回答しておきます。

大元の原因はPython3.x系しかサポートしていないパッケージ`sacrebleu`をPython2.x系にインストールしようとしていたことです。
インストール先環境をPython3.x系にする(`pip3`を使う)ことで解決となりました。

最初はPython2.x系のpip,setuptoolsも最新になっていなかったので段階的に状況が変わりました。

1. Python2.x系がデフォルトかつpip,setuptoolsが古い環境でPython3.x系用パッケージをインストールしようとしてエラー(最初)
2. Python2.x系のsetuptools,pipを更新して、エラーメッセージが変化
   (`open()`で`encoding`キーワードをサポートしていない=2.x系に3.x系をインストールしようとしている)
3. PyPIで`sacrebleu`は3.x系のみサポートの記述で、2.x/3.xの版数違いが判明
4. Python3.x系をインストール先に指定する方法の確認

---

以下は経緯詳細です。

`python setup.py egg_info error code 1`で検索すると以下あたりが見つかります。
[pip でインストールエラー: Command “python setup.py egg_info” failed](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/46978/26370)
[【Python】「Command “python setup.py egg_info” failed with error code 1 in …」の対処法](https://keymaso.com/programemory/python/pip-error-1/)
[pip install時の「“python setup.py egg_info” failed ...」エラー](https://www.ted027.com/post/python-psycopg2/)

最初のStackOverflowの記事は古かったのと、2番目の後半に良いことが書いてあったので紹介。

> エラーに慣れていない最初のうちは一番下のエラーメッセージのみを見て、Googleで検索し始める方も多いかもしれません。ぱっと見た感じだと訳がわからないですしね。
>   しかし案外、単純でしっかり「どの部分で」「どんなエラーが発生したか」、丁寧なライブラリなら「対処法はどうなのか」という内容まで書いてあるものなのです。

それから、エラーメッセージの最後`sacrebleu`がパッケージ名のようなので検索したGitHubのIssue欄に直近の課題があったので、それを紹介。
[v1.4.6 broke some imports #71](https://github.com/mjpost/sacrebleu/issues/71)

---

実際には`setuptools`は更新したけれど`pip`(setuptoolsと誤記されてましたが)は未だったので更新したら状況が変化したとのことで、そのエラーメッセージが追記された。

```
  File "/tmp/pip-install-jEHSxk/sacrebleu/setup.py", line 56, in get_version
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'sacrebleu.py'), encoding='utf-8') as fin:
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

その最後の`open()`の`encoding`が無効なキーワードということはPython 2.x系らしいということで、PyPIの情報を見たら3.x系のみと書いてあり、これが原因でしょうとコメント。
[sacrebleu・PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/sacrebleu/)  Programming Languageが`Python::3::Only`

インストール時にPython3系を指定する方法を聞かれたので、`pip3`を使ってみては？とコメントして解決となりました。

Comment: この回答を見てもどうやったら解決できたのかパッとは分からなかったです。大切な情報（`pip3`）をまず最初に書いて、補足的な情報は後ろの方にまとめる方が読みやすい回答になりそう、と感じました。如何でしょうか。